# Docker volumes not keeping data

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I've built a docker image with a python script that works with two different commands. The first one creates a file that is used when executing the second one.

As far as I know, I must use a Docker volume to store data between executions so I've created a volume with:

```
docker volume create myvol
```

To then use it when running the container

```
$ docker run myimg fit -v myvol:/data
model.h5 stored at /data
```

But then, when executing the other command it seems than the Docker directory /data is empty...

```
$ docker run predict -v myvol:/data
Error: /data/model.h5 not found
```

Is there any point that I'm missing?

Comment: Try something like this: `docker run -v myvol:/data myimg fit` and similar for the other command (note the placement of the -v option.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker command line is order sensitive. The syntax is:

```
docker $args_to_docker run $args_to_run $image_name $override_to_cmd
```

---

In your command you pass the `-v` option after the image name, so it becomes the `CMD` value in your container:

```
$ docker run myimg fit -v myvol:/data
model.h5 stored at /data
```

That runs the cmd `fit -v myvol:/data` inside the container.

---

The solution is to change the order if you want the `-v` to be an option to `run` and define a volume:

```
$ docker run -v myvol:/data myimg fit 
$ docker run -v myvol:/data predict
```

Comment: Yes, -v option was used as an image param! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the -v or --mount argument to the Docker run command. This will make sure that the data is really stored outside of the container, and you'll lose nothing.
See: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

When running these commands you need to remember that the first part of the -v option is always `<path_to_directory_on_host>:<path_to_directory_on_guest>`. You are able to use both absolute path's and relative paths to the directory on your host machine. So first thing is to create a directory on your host called data, move model.h5 into that directory, then mount it with the -v switch.

so if I had my data directory in C:\data on a windows directory I would use:

```
docker run <img_name> -v C:\data:/data
```

if I was on unix and my data directory was in /usr/data and I wanted it to be mounted on /data in my guest container then I would use

```
docker run <img_name> -v /usr/data:/data
```